# Calculate multivariate Gaussian from univariate Gaussian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, normal-distribution, covariance

I am currently trying to solve an exercise that involves estimating the position $\chi_t$ and and velocity $\dot\chi_t$ of a truck at time $t$. The truck moves on rails and is buffeted around by a random force $\ddot\chi_t$ with probability density function $P(\ddot\chi_t) = \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Time is discrete.

So I have already determined the following differential equation that describes the position and velocity of the truck relative to the last time step:

\begin{equation}
x_t 
= \begin{bmatrix} \chi_t \\ \dot\chi_{t} \end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix}1 & \Delta t \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\chi_{t-1} \\ \dot\chi_{t-1}\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\Delta t^2}{2} \\ \Delta t\end{bmatrix} \ddot\chi_{t-1}
\end{equation}

Now, I would like to compute the probability $P(x_t | x_{t-1})$. According to the solution, it is:

\begin{equation}
P(x_t|x_{t-1}) 
= \mathcal{N}(A_t x_{t-1}, R_t) \\
= \text{det}(2\pi R_t)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \text{ exp}\{-\frac{1}{2}(x_t - A_t x_{t-1})^T R_t^{-1} (x_t - A_t x_{t-1})\} \\ \text{ with } A_t = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \Delta t \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } R_t = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\Delta t^4}{4} & \frac{\Delta t^2}{2} \\ \frac{\Delta t^4}{4} & 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Could you please explain how to get from the first formula to the second one? I am specifically interested in how to calculate $R_t$.

Thank you for every answer!

Comment: Could you speak more clearly ? the x= [] , ... ! , i confused

Comment: @Cardinal: I added part of the description of the exercise I am currently struggling with -- hope that helps!

Comment: As i see, these location velocity equation have same RV ?

Comment: If the $X_t^{..}$ is a random variable

Comment: I mean it seems to be a process . Are you Sure about that ?

Comment: @Cardinal: I added the sample solution, which I do not understand yet. Hope this provides additional clarification.

Comment: I can tell you but my latex is terrible, it is simple

Answer (score 0):

note that, given to conditional probability:

$$ X_t = Ax_{t-1} + N $$

i think if we know the $x_{t-1}$ , then 
$$f_{{X_t}|{X_{t-1}}}(x_t|x_{t-1})$$
will be two dimensional Gaussian distributed. I am very busy currently, if it does not help you comment me.

Comment: You are right, f will be a bivariate Gaussian. But my question is: How do you calculate the covariance of the bivariate Gaussian?